# What is wrong with my render?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I am new to Blender and I have attached the photo of the render and the photo of the scene I'm working on. If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong please let me know, thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your camera is pointing in a random direction. Move it to correct position. Camera location and config is used for rendering.

Comment: First, make sure your render camera matches the viewport angle you like by pressing Ctrl + Alt + Numpad0 to snap the camera to view (I can't tell where the camera is in your scene so I don't know if you've done this already). Secondly, keep in mind that objects hidden in the viewport will still be visible in renders - make sure your hidden "venice gal" is not in the way of the camera.

Comment: if the above answers doesn't help you, please provide your blend file